# c# GUI problem in c# code

Tags: c#

I want to disable the GUI of my exe. Ho can i do that programatically? is there a way to disable a gui. Does the user32.dll accomplish this? Can someone give me a very short example? Thx

Comment: What do you mean disable? Not show the windows ? Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: I am working in a windows service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you want to do that? You are better off creating a service application that is running in the background and of course without gui.

**UPDATE**:

Here is the solution my friend: http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3336751/C-Tip-Placing-Your-C-Application-in-the-System-Tray.htm

Comment: well..if i have an exe that have a GUI how can i run it without displaying it's GUI using windows service? Can you give me some examples?thx Gens

Comment: @elisa: it may be simpler for you to create a new Windows Service project, which will give you the boiler plate code you need. Either copy your existing code into the new project, or copy the service code from the new project into your existing project.

Comment: I have an exe that i would like to run from a windows service. the thing is that exe has a gui interface. is there a way to run it in background? I dont want to see on desktop the gui from the exe.

Answer (score 2):

In your startup code (`Program.cs`, `Main` method) you create the main application Window (both in Windows.Forms and WPF). Here you can add code to bypass the creation of any application window, probably using a check for an argument on the commandline.

If your application is used from a windows service, you can test for [Envirnment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx), to see if there is a user watching you. I don't know what it returns if your app is called from a service (that is: a service executes your application), but then it is easy to add a commandline argument.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        // Test if any argument == "/batchmode" using upper or lowercase
        if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Any(a => string.Equals(a, "/batchmode", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            // Batch mode
        } else {
            // Interactive mode
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Note: This does not turn your application into a console/commandline application.